# Software for shared, searchable document dump (local hosting)

Tags: file-management, cloud-storage

Is there any opensource / free software for dumping files that can be shared with others and searched (eg. by filename or text content). Can be something like a locally hosted google drive (or like a more general version of GitHub gists (https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/)). My intended use case is that I am on a dev. team and all of the members have emails and reference articles that would be helpful to share with others, eg.

- enterprise tech. support communications that others could use when similar problem arise with those products,
- articles they've references when fixing some common issues (that again would be useful for others to reference if the problem arises again),
- etc.

It would be useful if everyone on the team could quickly *dump* and *search* these documents in a single place. We need to be able to host this locally on our own servers (that may also be in use for other things (ie. not necessarily a dedicated server)), since some of the data we would be dumping and sharing with each other may have sensitive info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the amount of work you are willing to do and if you want a proper document indexing tool, [sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html) would be my go-to answer. An alternative would be [lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/).

To send documents on a remote, you can use whatever fit your fancy as it hardly matter. From the top of my head, three different ways to easily transfer data:

- git repo
- samba share
- ftp server

Those two components are *easy* to setup, what matters the most though is the user interface. And that is a pain to implement. Those tools aren't a all-in-one service, but they'll give you enough liberty to fit whatever need you have. Beside, the way you send data on the remote doesn't need to be unique. If you generally require the documents to be versioned, yet a subset of your users do not have that necessity, then a mix of git and samba can be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found some potentially promising options while looking into this more. From this post (https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/4c794p/selfhosted_google_drive_alternative/), there is

- pydio (https://pydio.com/),
- seafile (https://www.seafile.com/en/home/),
- and owncloud (https://owncloud.org/features/) (seems to be the most popular).